# Mod Rewrite for Friendly URL 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I need to convert these 3 URLs:

1 - Mydomain/view/index.php?make=toyota&model=runner&color=white

2 - Mydomain/view/index.php?make=toyota&model=runner

3 - Mydomain/view/index.php?make=toyota

Into these:

1 - Mydomain/toyota/runner/white

2 - Mydomain/toyota/runner

3 - Mydomain/toyota

---

So I used an online Mod Rewrite tool generator and got this for the **FIRST** url:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view/index.php?make=$1&model=$2&color=$3 [L]

It worked perfect when I used the FIRST friently URL. Then I just copied and modified that RewriteRule twice and used them for the other two URLs, resulting into this:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view/index.php?make=$1&model=$2&color=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view/index.php?make=$1&model=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /view/index.php?make=$1 [L]

---

First friendly URL still works fine.
Second and third URLs stops on 500 Internal Server Error.

Would somebody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the destination uri you are rewriting to. To fix the loop error ,add the following at top of your htaccess right after **RewriteEngine on** line

```
RewriteRule index\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying @starkeen